# find main class in java

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Why java can't find my main?
this is my first java code

```
package MyPacage;

public class MyClass {

  public static void main(string[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
}
}
```

Comment: Because it's `String[] args`, not `string[] args`

Comment: Java is case sensitive, `string[]` should be `String[]` - your code won't even compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
}
```